# Java- Putting alphabet into an array with for loops

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add a letter to each slot in the arr[] with for loops, but the output displays only the letter 'a' several times. How can I fix this?

```
public class Bananas {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr = new char[26];
    int j = 0;
    for (char i = 'a' ; i <= 'z' ; i++) {
        while (j < arr.length){
            arr[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(arr[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one loop. This should do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr = new char[26];
    int j = 0;
    for (char i = 'a' ; i <= 'z' ; i++) {
        arr[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(arr[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I just needed to delete the while(j < arr.length)

Comment: @javajavahut Another neat trick when doing this sort of thing is `arr[j++]=i;`. Then you only need one line in the `for` loop.